# Launchpad use of dput

Tags: package-management, launchpad

According to [this page](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/udd-uploading.html), we are supposed to execute dput on our package to send it to our ppa. This confuses me because I already have my whole code on this ppa and the build is marked as successful. Do I really need to execute this command? If yes, why can't it just use the remote code?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have it in your PPA, then you (or something acting on your behalf) must have already run `dput` or its equivalent.  Perhaps you're using a source package recipe on Launchpad that does it for you?